# a crucial doubt on an ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have this Riccati ODE:

$y'(x) = -\kappa y(x)-0.5\beta^2y(x)^2+\xi$

and I know the solution of the analogous one

$y'(x) = -\kappa y(x)-0.5\beta^2y(x)^2+1$

leads to the closed-form solution

$y(x) = 2(e^{\gamma x}-1)/((\gamma+\kappa)(e^{\gamma x}-1)+2\gamma)$, where

$\gamma = \sqrt{\kappa^2+2\beta^2}$

How does the solution change with that $\xi$ instead of $1$?

Answer (score 0):

First write $y'$ as $\frac{d y}{dx}$ then if you divide through by $\xi$ you obtain $\frac{1}{\xi} \frac{d y}{d x} = -\frac{\kappa}{\xi} y -0.5\frac{\beta^2}{\xi}y^2+1$. Introduce new scaled variables $z = \xi x$, $\kappa' = \frac{\kappa}{\xi}, \beta' = \frac{\beta}{\sqrt{\xi}}$ and in these new variables you have

$$\frac{d y}{d z} = -\kappa' y -0.5\beta'^2y^2+1$$